# Finiteness of the integral of the square of a non-negative continuous unbounded function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function with $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$. Can we conclude that $\int_{0}^{\infty}(f(x))^2dx<\infty$? I understand that the conclusion is true if $f$ is bounded by some positive $M$ because then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f^2<M\int_{0}^{\infty}f<\infty$. But I wonder if there is a counterexample when $f$ is unbounded.

Any help or comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=x^{-1/2}e^{-x}$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is it continuous at zero?

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that assumption. Still the conclusion fails. Start by finding a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $\int f$ is small while $\int f^2$ is large.

Comment: By continuity $\int_0^{M} f^{2}(x)dx<\infty$ for any $M$. Concentrate on what happens near $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f=\sum n1_{(n,n+n^{-3})}$ has these integrability properties. modify this to get a  continuous function.